# Convert dataframe for time varying analysis

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I want to convert my data framefrom column wise to row wise

```
structure(list(ID = 1:2, Age = c(45L, 60L), SGLT_v1_0_3 = 1:0, 
    SGLT_time_0_3 = c(92L, 92L), SGLT_v1_3_6 = 0:1, SGLT_time_3_6 = c(183L, 
    183L), SGLT_v1_6_9 = 1:0, SGLT_time_6_9 = c(285L, 285L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

  ID Age SGLT_v1_0_3 SGLT_time_0_3 SGLT_v1_3_6
1  1  45           1            92           0
2  2  60           0            92           1
  SGLT_time_3_6 SGLT_v1_6_9 SGLT_time_6_9
1           183           1           285
2           183           0           285
```

I want the dataframe to look like:

```
  ID Age SGLT_time SGLT_v1
1  1  45   92     1
2  2  60   92     0
3  1  45  183     0
4  2  60  183     1
5  1  45  285     1
6  2  60  285     0
```

I tried the pivot_longer but cant seem to get that right as it does not provide correct data. I ma trying to perform time varying analysis on my dat frame but need the data to be in row wise format prior to doing any analysis. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pivot_longer()`.

```
library(tidyr)
df |> 
  pivot_longer(
    contains("SGLT_"),
    names_to = ".value",
    names_pattern = "(SGLT_time|SGLT_v1)"
  )
```

**output**

```
     ID   Age SGLT_v1 SGLT_time
  <int> <int>   <int>     <int>
1     1    45       1        92
2     1    45       0       183
3     1    45       1       285
4     2    60       0        92
5     2    60       1       183
6     2    60       0       285
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(ID = 1:2, Age = c(45L, 60L), SGLT_v1_0_3 = 1:0, 
    SGLT_time_0_3 = c(92L, 92L), SGLT_v1_3_6 = 0:1, SGLT_time_3_6 = c(183L, 
    183L), SGLT_v1_6_9 = 1:0, SGLT_time_6_9 = c(285L, 285L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I like the use of `.value` here!

Comment: I ran into eorror when I used your suggested code The error is as follows: Problem while evaluationg pivot_longer, Caused by error in contains() unsused arguent (names_to = ".value",
    names_pattern = "(SGLT_time|SGLT_v1)")

Comment: I fixed the typo error but new error that says regex should define 1 groups 0 found